# migrating fancybox 1 to fancybox 3

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fairly massive (for me) website developed using fancybox 1 and I'm trying to upgrade to Fancybox 3, but there are issues. All of my iframe contents have about 100px height. I have spent about 1 week trying to find the answer and need to throw the question out to the experts.

Here is a typical example

HTML code

```
<a href="syllabus/s04.1.htm" class="syl"><span class="def3" onMouseOver="this.className='def3_on'" onMouseOut="this.className='def3'">Syllabus 
      ref: 4.1</span></a>
```

The class "syl" is referenced in an external jquery javascript:

```
 $(".syl").fancybox({
        'width'         : '90%',
        'height'        : '90%',
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'overlayOpacity'    :  0.6,
        'overlayColor'      : '#944',
        'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
        'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
        'type'      : 'iframe'
     });
```

This is inside a document ready call and works great with fancybox 1, but now that I have linked fancybox 3, the iframe is full fancybox size but linked src file appears to be complete, but only 100px (or so) high, normal width.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, I am curious - did you check docs while spending a week on this task? If so, then what part was unclear?

Comment: Yes - I have read through the Fancybox docs, but could not see any examples of how to implement iframes in external js

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what "implement iframes in external js" means and how that is different from https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#iframe

Comment: I understand that fancybox can be initiated from the HTML, but I would like to send the information from HTML to an external .js file to allow it to respond depending on the specific document that is being "fancyboxed". I can do it generically using:
 $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
     iframe : {
         css : {
             width :  '80%',
    height : '80%'
         }
     }
 });
But would like to have a class or id in the HTML which would allow a non-generic to format the FB appropriately

Comment: In other words, I wold like to replace $("[data-fancybox]") with something more specific like $("[data-fancybox].style") for example and I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are using options that do not exist in v3. If you wish to set custom dimensions, either use CSS or JS (like `iframe : {css : {width : '90%'}}`), see docs https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#iframe for samples.

Anyway, since you did not provide a link to live page/demo where your setup could be inspected, it is not possible to give an exact answer.

Comment: The documentation refers almost exclusively to setting up fancybox directly from the HTML document. What I would like to do is have a class or id that could be read by fancybox in the external .js file and formatted appropriately.
I understand that I can use the generic:
 $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
     iframe : {
         css : {
             width :  '80%',
    height : '80%'
         }
     }
 });

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it by looking at the source code of some examples.

In the HTML you have to declare the data-fancybox tag with an identifier. In the example below, data-fancybox='swf'

```
<a href="#" data-src="Section00-bonding/swf/sigmapi.swf" class="swf" data-fancybox='swf' data-type="iframe">File Name</a>
```

and then in the external .js file:

```
$("[data-fancybox='swf']").fancybox({
    iframe : {
        css : {
            width :  '70%',
            height : '90%'
        }
    }
});
```

This means that I can now decide on the format of the fancybox depending on the type of file that I am displaying.

I am sorry if I wasn't clear with the question before.